# nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [limit]

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

```
public java.util.Collection findEstablishmentProfessionalsByUsernameEstId(
            java.lang.String espUseUsername, java.lang.Integer espEstId, Integer limit) throws GenericBusinessException {
        try {
            
            ArrayList paramList = new ArrayList();
            List valueList = new ArrayList();
                
            paramList.add(new String("espEstId"));
            valueList.add(espEstId);
            
            paramList.add(new String("espUseUsername"));
            valueList.add(espUseUsername);
            
            String queryString = "from "
                    + EstablishmentProfessionalsBean.class.getName()
                    + " e where e.espEstId = :espEstId and e.espRecordStatus='approved' and e.espUseUsername=:espUseUsername and e.espShow=1";
            // Add a an order by on all primary keys to assure reproducable
            // results.
            
            queryString += " order by e.espSurname ASC,e.espInitials ASC,e.espExtClinicName ASC";
            if(limit != null && limit.intValue() > 0){
                paramList.add(new String("limit"));
                valueList.add(limit);
            }       
            String params [] = (String []) paramList.toArray (new String [paramList.size ()]);
            List list = hibernateTemplate.findByNamedParam(queryString,params, valueList.toArray());
            return list;
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            log.error("DataAccessException", e);
            throw new GenericBusinessException(e);
        } finally {
            log.debug("finished findEstablishmentProfessionalsByUsernameEstId((java.lang.String espUseUsername, java.lang.Integer espEstId, Integer limit)");
        }
    }

following are the stack trace
```

**Stack Trace**

> com.riomed.cellma.exception.GenericBusinessException:
> org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateQueryException: could not
> locate named parameter [limit]; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named
> parameter [limit] at
> com.riomed.cellma.session.CellmaFacade.findEstablishmentProfessionalsByUsernameEstId(CellmaFacade.java:30866)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) at
> org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:310)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
> at
> org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
> at
> com.sun.proxy.$Proxy321.findEstablishmentProfessionalsByUsernameEstId(Unknown
> Source) at
> com.riomed.cellma.cellma.util.GeneralWebLayerUtils.addAjaxExtraDetailsEntryForQucId(GeneralWebLayerUtils.java:4252)
> at
> com.riomed.cellma.cellma.util.AssessmentsSaveQuestionsUtils.saveReferralRecordForQuestionAnswered(AssessmentsSaveQuestionsUtils.java:178)
> at
> com.riomed.cellma.actions.SaveQuestionsResultAction.execute(SaveQuestionsResultAction.java:239)
> at
> org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:421)
> at
> org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:226)
> at
> org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1164)
> at
> org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:415)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) at
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:167)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> com.riomed.cellma.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:128)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> com.riomed.cellma.filter.SensitiveDataCheckFilter.doFilter(SensitiveDataCheckFilter.java:1944)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at com.riomed.cellma.filter.CSRFFilter.doFilter(CSRFFilter.java:1726)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at com.riomed.cellma.filter.XSSFilter.doFilter(XSSFilter.java:2301) at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> com.riomed.cellma.filter.PatientSelectionCheckFilter.doFilter(PatientSelectionCheckFilter.java:416)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> com.riomed.cellma.filter.AuthorisationFilter.doFilter(AuthorisationFilter.java:1598)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> com.riomed.cellma.filter.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:287)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> com.riomed.cellma.filter.MessageDisplayFilter.doFilter(MessageDisplayFilter.java:138)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
> at
> org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
> at
> org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
> at
> org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:239)
> at
> net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:215)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
> at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.service(AjpProcessor.java:396)
> at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
> at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1591)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) Caused by:
> org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateQueryException: could not
> locate named parameter [limit]; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named
> parameter [limit] at
> org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:642)
> at
> org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:412)
> at
> org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:424)
> at
> org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
> at
> org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.findByNamedParam(HibernateTemplate.java:943)
> at
> com.riomed.cellma.session.CellmaFacade.findEstablishmentProfessionalsByUsernameEstId(CellmaFacade.java:30862)
> ... 83 more Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could
> not locate named parameter [limit] at
> org.hibernate.engine.query.ParameterMetadata.getNamedParameterDescriptor(ParameterMetadata.java:75)
> at
> org.hibernate.engine.query.ParameterMetadata.getNamedParameterExpectedType(ParameterMetadata.java:81)
> at
> org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.determineType(AbstractQueryImpl.java:413)
> at
> org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:383)
> at
> org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.applyNamedParameterToQuery(HibernateTemplate.java:1253)
> at
> org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$31.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:949)
> at
> org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:419)
> ... 86 more

Comment: Post the error stacktrace here

Comment: please check i have added stack trace

Answer (score 2):

In your query:

```
e where e.espEstId = :espEstId and e.espRecordStatus='approved'
and e.espUseUsername=:espUseUsername and e.espShow=1
```

you have these namedParameter(s):

- :espEstId
- :espUseUsername

You want to replace a namedParameter `limit`

Because in your code you've written so:

```
paramList.add(new String("limit"));
valueList.add(limit);
```

But there's no :limit in your query, so you have this error.